# Handling gzipped web content with WWW::Mechanize/::GZip

Tags: perl, gzip, mechanize, scrape

The question is simple, how to handle content that is gzipped. And not only handle that content but fill in forms and do all the stuff that you'd normally do with WWW::Mechanize. I'm trying to do a simple task:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

#use WWW::Mechanize;
use WWW::Mechanize::GZip;
use IO::File;



my $mech = WWW::Mechanize::GZip->new(agent =>
     'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 9.0; en-US;)',

    ssl_opts => {
    SSL_verify_mode => IO::Socket::SSL::SSL_VERIFY_NONE,
    verify_hostname => 0,
});


$mech->get('https://');

print $mech->content;
```

I've edited out the URL for obvious reasons. Anyway this yields nothing. Although at one point this did return the decoded content, which is quite strange.

I also managed to decode the content within WWW::Mechanize, however still I have no idea how to submit the forms that I need.

Comment: Could you provide a website that only sends out gzipped content so we can try this? The docs of WWW::Mechanize::GZip say it can do everything that a normal $mech can do. This should work out of the box.

Comment: Hi. Unfortunately, I can't share this exact site. However, it seems like it might have been misconfigured, as when testing with other gzipped sites, it seems to be working.